# Foreign key exception on INSERT with Linq-to-SQL but can't figure out why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_JobList_aspnet_Membership". The
>   conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\JOBPOST\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF",
>   table "dbo.aspnet_Membership", column
>   'UserId'.The statement has been
>   terminated.

My FK_JobList_aspnet_Membership setup is:

- Primary table (`aspnet_membership`)
- foreign key table (`JobList`)
- use column `UserId(uniqueidentifier)` for both tables, currently only set 2 UserId

`JobList` has its auto indexable primary key int `JobId`. No Action on Insert and update attribute, Delete set to Cascade

In the dbml, I also set `UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never` for `JobList` Table

I don't understand why the exception happens, since I use membership service after user login. It should have no conflict. BTW, I am sure there is no other duplicate function for Inserting Item. Though throw exception, the new row data has been successfully inserted with correct userId. It keeps throwing this kind of exception for each time Inserting Item.

```
protected void LinqDataSourceDetail_Inserting(object sender, LinqDataSourceInsertEventArgs e) 
{        
    if (Page.IsValid == true)     
    {               
        JobPostDataContext db = new JobPostDataContext();

        JobList newJob = new JobList();
        newJob.JobTitle = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TB_JobTitle")).Text;
        newJob.Summary = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TB_Summary")).Text;
        newJob.Detail = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TB_Detail")).Text;
        newJob.CompanyName = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TB_CompanyName")).Text;
        newJob.CompanyEmail = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TB_CompanyEmail")).Text;
        String date = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TB_PostDate")).Text;
        newJob.PostDate = (DateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        newJob.IsTop = false;
        newJob.UserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;

        db.JobLists.InsertOnSubmit(newJob); 
        db.SubmitChanges();          
     } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not inserting NULL as FK?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line with the `InsertOnSubmit` and inspect the `newJob` object - is that `UserId` set to a valid GUID? Does that GUID indeed exist in the aspnet_membership table??

Answer (score -1):

It means that the guid returned by `(Guid)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey` doesn't appear in the `aspnet_membership` table.

This is probably because `Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)` is not finding the current user. In turn this is probably because `User.Identity.Name` is not in the `aspnet_membership` table either.

Suggested resolution:

- output User.Identity.Name. One way to do this is to `throw new Exception(User.Identity.Name)`
- Check that the name appears in the membership table.

When you inevitably discover that it does not, you can continue your debugging from there.